# Build project without Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

How to build `Android Studio project` using `gradle` without installing `IDE`, if i never installed `gradle`, but i have `android sdk` and `jdk`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the project was created with Android Studio, it should already have a `gradlew` script in the root directory, which you can use to execute Gradle from the command line (e.g. `gradlew build`).

Comment: Should i create local.properties file and specify path to android sdk?

Comment: @Dima, yeah, you need to specify the SDK path in either `$ANDROID_HOME` env variable or `sdk.dir` property in `local.properties`. (Note that if the `local.properties` file exists, you *must* have `sdk.dir` in there.)

Comment: What if the project wasn't created with Android Studio?

Answer (score 3):

**Steps to Build using Command line:**

Open CMD and navigate it to project's root directory(You can also navigate to directory first using file Explore and then right click there keeping SHIFT key pressed and select **`Open Command window Here`** from available option)

**For Debug Builds Run the command :**

```
     gradlew assembleDebug
```

**For Release Builds :**

First you need to write the signing configuration inside your module's build.gradle file like

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 14
    }

    signingConfigs {

         mySigning{
            storeFile file("YOUR_KEYSTORE_PATH")
            storePassword "KEY_STORE_PASSWORD"
            keyAlias "KEY_ALIAS"
            keyPassword "ALIAS_PASSWORD"
         }
     }

     buildTypes {

          release {
             runProguard false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
             signingConfig signingConfigs.mySigning
             zipAlign true
          }
      }
  }
```

After Configuration Run the command

```
     gradlew assembleRelease
```

**While executing the command it will automatically download required gradle version in you machine** . If you want to change the gradle version you have to configure it in build.gradle file inside wrapper task if you have created

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.4'  //1.4 is version
}
```

And if applicable you have to change `distributionUrl` in `gradle-wrapper.properties` file  located at **$ROOT_PROJECT_DIR/gradle** like

```
   distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-bin.zip
```